# Can WebAuthenticationBroker work with persistent cookies?

Tags: windows-runtime, single-sign-on

From the documentation on the [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class, this object appears to exist to support Single-Sign-On scenarios as well as the OAuth2 flow I'm trying to use it for. As part of its behaviour, it seems to create a completely separate browsing environment from the rest of the system and actively purges all the persistent cookies generated via a sign-on process.

This causes me the problem that each time my user enters my application, they will be prompted to sign in with their credentials. This is counter to my expectations around SSO and would seem to make this class unsuitable for most scenarios.

Is there some way to make the cookies persist, as they would do in a normal browser, so that I don't have to 2-factor sign into my Google account yet again?